# Display Woocommerce Product Data in Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, custom-post-type

I want to be able to adopt Woocommerce products page into my Custom post type

so that I can add shipping, attributes, variations etc..

[image]

Currently I can add my CPT to WC cart successfully through adding a price meta on it, but I think i need to integrate all the product data into my CPT not just price

Comment: Instead you should have to create a new product type that extends WC_Product, if you want to use and be able to adopt Woocommerce products settings, classes and inherited methods on it.

Comment: I think this will be a lot of work and I don't even know where to start or how to do it :-)

Comment: For me it seems much more work to use a custom post type that should be like a product…

Comment: I agree with you @LoicTheAztec